# Starting point in learning Core Data on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, core-data

What is the starting point for Core Data in order to get involved quickly?
Any useful link, blog or book or other resourse?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might be interested in video of the Core Data class from my Advanced iPhone Development course, which is [available for free on iTunes U](https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/advanced-iphone-development-spring-2010/id407243032).  I walk through Core Data and how to use it in an iPhone application.

If you log in to the [iPhone Developer Program site](https://developer.apple.com/iphone/), you have access to a series of videos for free, among which is the session "Working with Core Data" (in the Advanced Videos section).

For more advanced information, the [WWDC 2010 session videos](https://developer.apple.com/videos/archive/) have the sessions 137  "Optimizing Core Data Performance on iPhone OS" and 118 "Mastering Core Data".

Answer (score 4):

Besides the Apple documentation, you will find extremely useful the following book:

[Core Data](http://pragprog.com/titles/mzcd/core-data), by Marcus Zarra.

Answer (score 3):

I did start with Apple's doc which is clear and complete.

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html

I'm quite sure there is a tutorial over there.

Core Data is not iPhone only, but i-phone specific elements are clearly indicated.

Answer (score 2):

Marcus Zarra's book is awesome and I love it, but I got started with [More iPhone 3 Development](http://apress.com/book/view/143022505X) from APress.  A few chapters in the book walk through creating a Core-Data based app on the iPhone, and the code is actually pretty usable in further projects.

Answer (score 0):

I've been reading through [Pro Core Data for iOS](http://www.apress.com/9781430233558) which seems to go over the concepts pretty well. It was able to get me up and running with a basic Core Data application pretty quickly. That and looking at the demo projects helped a lot.