# Simple Core Data Example App?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-data

I am trying to learn about core data on the iPhone, and I am looking for a simple Core Data example app.

The problem is, all the example apps I've seen are either *too* simple (just one view and one data object), or so full of extra functions that it's hard to see what's relevant (Apple's example apps).

I'm looking for an example app with:

- an ordinary cascading to-many relationship (e.g. Company > Departments > Employees)
- a simple drill-down interface (e.g. click on a company to see list of departments; click on a department to see list of employees; click on an employee to see name and address)
- simple editing (press plus for modal view to add company/department/employee)

... so I can learn the basics about passing contexts between views, NSFetchedResultsController etc.

Does anyone know of such a thing?

Thanks!

Comment: @TechZen yep, that's pretty much the problem! All the examples seem to leap from ultra-simple to "look what I can do!" with no intermediate stage. Apple illustrate Core Data with simple parent-child-grandchild examples in their docs, but don't provide the corresponding example apps.

Comment: I recommend sitting down and trying to recreate a simple example from scratch without referring to the example just to make sure you understand the basic concepts before moving. I've wasted a lot of time over the years not by not investing in mastering the basics before leaping to the more complex. A lot of times, mastering the basics gives you that epiphany you need to understand an entire API.

Comment: @TechZen you are very wise. I can do the basics, but my own app is more complex, hence my frustration with the leap. Maybe I need to pause and make my own intermediate test app. If it's any good, maybe I'll post it up for others!

Comment: You might also be interested in some of the Core Data resources within the answers of this question: [Starting point in learning Core Data on iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164300/starting-point-in-learning-core-data-on-iphone).  The examples I give for my class might fall on the "too simple" side for you, but I do delve a little bit further into the framework than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend Marcus Zarra's [Core Data book](http://pragprog.com/titles/mzcd/core-data) and the examples [therein](http://pragprog.com/titles/mzcd/source_code). He takes one example app that starts off very simple and incrementally adds complexity.

RecipeCT is the project that I would suggest looking at first. Having the book would help you navigate from project to project as the basic Recipes app transforms.

Comment: Thanks! I started programming with another Pragmatic Bookshelf book (Beginning Mac Programming by Tim Isted) which is also excellent - it's got me this far from scratch!

Answer (score 3):

Try the example found here: [Wiley Code Examples](http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0470481072,descCd-DOWNLOAD.html)

Click on Chapter 18 - Downloads.

Hope this helps.

- Let It Be Known

Comment: Thanks. This is the best example I've seen so far, but it's still just parent and child displayed in a single view (plus an extra view for editing). I'm hoping to find something that shows drilling down through parent-child-grandchild in a view controller.

Comment: Sorry - meant "in a navigation controller".